# Why does the while loop not stop and .write() not work? python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a very basic login/register system, when I try to create an account it keeps asking me to insert username and password without stop. Also why do the username and password that I insert dont get written in the files?

```
loop = True
while loop:
    userName = input("Username: ")
    passWord = input("Password: ")
    uFile_read_mode = open("usernameDetails.txt", "r+")
    uFile_read = uFile_read_mode.readlines()

    usernames_list = []
    for line in uFile_read:
        usernames_list.append(line[:-1])
        if userName in usernames_list:
            print("Username already exists.")
            print("Please choose another one.")
            uFile_read_mode.close()
        else:
            loop = False
            uFile_append = open("usernameDetails.txt", "a+")
            uFile_append.write(userName + " ")
            uFile_append.close()
            pFile_append = open("passwordDetails.txt", "a+")
            pFile_append.write(passWord + " ")
            pFile_append.close()
            print("Account successfully created.")
```

Comment: You maybe never enter the body of the loop which starts `for line in uFile_read:` hence you never actually do anything with the variables `userName` and `passWord`. But, without a [mcve] (which you haven't supplied) we can do nothing but guess.

Comment: @JohnColeman I read that page about minimal reproducible example but didn't quite understand what that is, I tried searching on other places but it all said the same thing. From what I could understand, is it just a shorter version of the code, that still gives the same result? If so, the code I posted is already as short as I can make it, there are no error messages when I run the code, the only problem as I mentioned above, and as you mentioned aswell, is that the code inside the ` for line in uFile_read: ` doesn't seem to be executed, thus not stopping the while loop.

Comment: At a minimum, you would need to show the state of the file "usernameDetails.txt" at the start of the code.

Comment: @JohnColeman If you mean if the file is open or closed at the start of the code, it has to be closed since the line `uFile_read_mode = open("usernameDetails.txt", "r+")` is the first line that I open/mention the file.

Comment: What are the *contents* of the files in question? I'm guessing that they are blank. If there are no lines to iterate over, then the loop is never entered. You haven't thought about what your code should do when there are no userfnames in the file.

Comment: I thought about that and so I added 1 word to both the usernameDetails.txt and passwordDetails.txt, but the result is still the same

Comment: When I added a word to the files, the code runs as it should (although you probably want to make sure you are adding newline characters in the `write`)